# SQL Server user unable to see/use sequence

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I can create a sequence and select values under 1 database user but even after granting update to public another DB user is still unable to use/see the sequence.

What do I need to request our remote DBA team to do to make the other DB users able to use the sequence?

I am writing code using Management Studio and database version is SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.5026.0).

I can create and use sequences under my account:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.seq_test;

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.seq_test;

GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.seq_test TO PUBLIC;

SELECT * FROM SYS.SEQUENCES;
```

But when other user runs

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.seq_test
```

they get an error "invalid object", and when they run

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.SEQUENCES;
```

they get no rows returned

Comment: Please format your SQL sequences as code. It will make the question more readable.

Comment: Why don't you just give your DBAs instructions as to what you want to achieve and let them deal with it?  Are they really just there to type in SQL for you?

Comment: `UPDATE` permissions [should be all that is needed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#security)

Comment: Have you checked you and the other user are in the same database, on the same server?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Looks like it was either user error or possibly sequence not visible until other user logged in and out again?